# WebResource.axd error - "This is an invalid webresource request."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, webresource.axd

I have a large .NET 2 web application that has been updated to target the .NET 4.0 framework. Since the update, I am seeing the following error recurring regularly in my logs:

> This is an invalid webresource
>   request.

The resource requested is "**~/WebResource.axd**"
As far as I can tell, the request looks fine in that there's a long querystring with keys (keys are **d**, **t**) and values for those keys.

Has the mechanism for generating requests to WebResource.axd changed between framework versions? Does anyone have any advice about how to go about debugging this issue?

**Edit:**
I found a way to decrypt the web resource request querystring (code follows). The requested resource is `pCSSFriendly|CSSFriendly.CSS.Menu.css` which looks like an issue with addressing the CSSFriendly.MenuAdapter resource which is used by the application. That leading "p" looks like it could be the problem.

```
private string DecryptWebResource(string urlEncodedData)
{
    byte[] encryptedData = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(urlEncodedData);
    Type machineKeySection = typeof(MachineKeySection);
    Type[] paramTypes = new Type[] { typeof(bool), typeof(byte[]), typeof(byte[]), typeof(int), typeof(int) };
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo encryptOrDecryptData = machineKeySection.GetMethod("EncryptOrDecryptData", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, paramTypes, null);

    try
    {
        byte[] decryptedData = (byte[])encryptOrDecryptData.Invoke(null, new object[] { false, encryptedData, null, 0, encryptedData.Length });
        string decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedData);
        return decrypted;
    }
    catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
    {
    }

    return String.Empty;
}
```

Comment: do you see the user agent making the request in your logs? Is the user agent a bot rather than a regular browser. If it's a browser, is it always a specific browser?

Comment: Any chance you can show use the actual request url (with any modifications required by you)?

Comment: @Shiv - user agent is not a bot, no specific browser. actual requested url is: "/WebResource.axd?d=mMV7RYieQ41tpTxPsIlhBcWLOEc_3Zk34EIeVXcAdmd_v2A7LNXIx4APFE1uwxEunSxoFByBQlJC-llRVaRlyz7B-OlDyh0CM5hgc8nbEkFNjAFf0&t=634273401161119442"

Comment: I have the same problem here. New server, same code (copy/pasted entire site) works on a previous server. I did encounter this problem once, but I can't remember how I solved it.

Comment: After reading this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676232/webresource-axd-problem-in-asp-net-2-0 I noticed that the server wasn't even in the correct month (it indicated june, while we are in november). I fixed it, and... it works ! Really weird.

Comment: No, the leading "p" is not the problem: I tried to decode the d param of working WebResource requests, and the leading "p" is there too.

Comment: Just to save others the trouble; To implement the code chunk, you will need to reference System.Web and System.Configuration, and add ... using System.Web; using System.Web.Configuration;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Has the mechanism for generating requests to WebResource.axd changed between framework versions?

Apparently applying security updates (and certainly changing framework major versions) can alter the client-server interaction involving WebResource.axd in such a way as to cause this error.  We saw this error after applying patches and the cause seems to be client side caching http://forums.asp.net/t/1609380.aspx - the errors went away after 30 days or so.