# Webresource.axd Syntax Error in Asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, webresource.axd

I am getting a strange problem in my asp.net application after deployment when i browse my web application with IE it doesn't display properly and ends with an error description like below:

> ```
> Syntax Error
> WebResource.axd
> ```

I think it is important to notify here that this application works perfectly when run from VS built-in web server.

Any idea how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered similar problem when publishing to a server with different time zone.

Try setting your computer time as server's - if it is different, of course.Then build and publish the application.