# How to resolve “This is an invalid webresource request” error in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd, obout

After upgrading ASP .Net 3.5 app to .NET 4.5.2 we started receiving numerous “This is an invalid webresource request” errors.

We have traced the error to missing css from [Obout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988691/webresource-axd-error-this-is-an-invalid-webresource-request) control dll. The control is used widely and we cannot replace it.

The upgrade was performed month and half ago and we still receive the same number of errors.

I am aware of other Stackoverflow [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988691/webresource-axd-error-this-is-an-invalid-webresource-request) regarding the same problem, but some of the answers suggest problem disappears with time. This has not happened in our case yet, almost 2 months after upgrade.

Comment: So it sounds like you've determined Obout controls are the source of the problem. Have you tried removing the reference to the Obout controls and readding it? According to their site it's compatible with 4.5. Additionally according to your link the problem was client side caching, if you clear the cookies does it fix itself?

Comment: I would expect caches would recycle after more than a month? Will try removing and adding references.

Comment: Most of the time when I ignore things because I'm pretty sure they won't happen it ends up being that thing :)

Comment: what about creating a module which would handle the specifix axd request and serve the css (perhaps from the old version)

Comment: That sounds interesting, what do you mean when you say module?

Comment: What browsers are receiving this error?  I seem to remember a bug in IE8 that has to do with WebResource.axd errors and the browser handling long query strings incorrectly and adding incorrect padding.

Comment: It's an intranet app and 99% of our users are using latest version of firefox.

Comment: Most likely it is because the framework doesn't match, Its like a french person understanding Spanish. You Could copy your project and setting it to 4.5 and seeing if you get the same issue. If you do get the same issue contact Obout if you haven't already.

Answer (score -1):

Not really sure how that happened but try adding this code to your web config

And then in your IIS, under Machine Key for the website, we have 
Encryption Method = SHA1
Decryption Method = DES

make sure all the checkboxes for Validation key and Decryption key are unchecked.
Note that "xxx" and "yyy" are in the key fields.

After making this change, you may need to recycle your app pool, and clear browser caches.